# How format strings get their arguments from the stack

Tags: stack

I'm playing around with format strings and am finding it difficult to understand, how the arguments are retrieved from the stack. This is my example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i = 123321;
  char a[] = "AAAAA";
  printf(argv[1]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Now, I've been running the program in a debugger, experimenting with input, so things like "AAA %x %x" and looking at the memory segment between the stack pointer and the base pointer, trying to figure out which format specifiers got replaced with which words.

This lead to some confusion. I ran the program with "AAAAA %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %p %p %x %x %x %x %x", as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Afterwards, I examined the memory starting at the stack pointer, going towards and beyond the base pointer. As can be seen by the 0x4141414141 and 0x1e1b9ca70c100 values that are output, which are the array a[]="AAAAA" and the value i=123321 (=0x1e1b9), I was able to get my local variables output to me using the format string. However, if I replace the two %p with two %x, then I only get part of the array (since it's larger than one word) and 0x001e1b9 (the value of i) is not output at all. 
Why wont these 4-byte values be popped off the stack? I have to use %p, otherwise it just seems to skip these words on the stack and pops of different stuff. Does this have something to do with how the local variables are aligned on the stack?

Thanks,
Brick

Comment: Calling conventions and variadic functions on x86-64 are complicated. See: [amd64 and va_arg](http://blog.nelhage.com/2010/10/amd64-and-va_arg/)